# Disable mobile data for Firebase listeners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-wifi, event-listener

I'm creating an Android app which sends a significant amount of data to and from Firebase. Because of this, I don't want it to be able to eat up the user's mobile data. Is there any way to set up the listeners such that they only collect data when wifi is on?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the listener to your database when the **wifi** is **on** such as:

```
database.child("your_key_name").addValueEventListener(this);
```

and when the **wifi** is **off** you can remove the listener, so that your app can't receive any data from the firebase such as:

```
database.child("your_key_name").removeEventListener(this);
```

You can check on **wifi status** inside this function:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
```

See more details in the following link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: How do you set it up such that the app would constantly listen for a change in wifi state?

Comment: @user6462035: Some docs for [monitoring connection state](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).